How to deal damage only on (some) frame(s) on attack?
I'm making a game by LibGdx, my character can attack and have animation for it, but I want that the attack only deal damage to enemy only in specific frame of animation, not just in start/end of the animation.
I made a hitEntities array to store the enemy that character hit, and only add hitEntities when the current frame is the frame that I want to deal damage.
Update() method call everytime my character draw().
This approach works sometimes, but sometimes it makes the attack miss. I think there can be another way that can be more optimal.
 public void update(float statetime){
        if(owner.isDead()) return;
        if(frameToDealDamageIdx < frameToDealDamage.length && animation.getKeyFrameIndex(statetime) == frameToDealDamage[frameToDealDamageIdx]){
            dealDamage();
        }
    }

public void addHitEntity(Entity entity){
        statetime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if(frameToDealDamageIdx >= frameToDealDamage.length || animation.getKeyFrameIndex(statetime) != frameToDealDamage[frameToDealDamageIdx]) return;
        if(hitEntities.contains(entity, false)) return;
        hitEntities.add(entity);
    }


I solved this in my game by extending the default Rectangle with my own CollisionRectangle object.
Collisions are checked with the overlaps() method as normal, but each CollisionRectangle has a unique identifier, and a set consisting of other CollisionRectangles it has overlapped. For a collision to be considered valid, the two CollisionRectangle objects must overlap and not have overlapped before. There's also a reset() method since I pool these objects.
public class CollisionRectangle extends Rectangle {

    private String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    private Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();

    public CollisionRectangle(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        super(x, y, w, h);
    }

    public void reset() {
        uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        set.clear();
    }

    public boolean overlaps(Actor a) {
        if (!super.overlaps(a.bounds)) {
            return false; // not overlapping
        }
        if (set.contains(a.bounds.getUuid())) {
            return false; // already collided
        }
        set.add(a.bounds.getUuid());
        return true;
    }

    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

}


This is a good solution to check for collision once, but my problem is to control that we only check collision/deal damage on on(some) specific frame(s)

I wonder if the CollisionRectangle can have some context about those specific frames. Then you could extend the overlaps() function to check if those requirements there. For example, if it's not one of those specific frames, early return false?

yeh we have same thought, that's the way I'm using
